# How to redirect page on login using react-router-dom V5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router-dom` 5.2.0 for routing in a `create-react-app`. I'm trying to use react-router to perform redirects and protect routes.

The landing page is `/`. This page contains the login/signup.

If login is successful, the page should redirect to `/home`. Along with this, the `/home` and `/explore` paths should now become available.

Currently, I'm managing login status using state (redux). The variable `authState` contains the `isUserLoggedIn` state. If `isUserLoggedIn` is true, that means the user is logged in. If the login form on submit has the username and password as "test" and "test", I update the `isUserLoggedIn` to true. By default `isUserLoggedIn` is `false`. So, when `isUserLoggedIn` become `true`, the page should redirect from `/` to `/home` which is not happening.

After a lot of searching, I came across (and used) the following piece of code. Even though this protects my routes when the `isUserLoggedIn` state is set to false; it does not however redirect the page to `/home` upon successful login.

What am I doing wrong here? Also, I couldn't find a decent enough explanation for this online. I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain what's happening.

```
/** @jsx jsx */
/** @jsxFrag React.Fragment */
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/core"
import tw from "twin.macro"
import "tailwindcss/dist/base.css"

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom"

import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import Landing from "./features/landing/Landing"
import Home from "./features/home/Home"
import Explore from "./features/explore/Explore"

import { selectorAuth } from "./authSlice"

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authState = useSelector(selectorAuth)

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authState.isUserLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div tw="flex flex-col bg-green-100 min-h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/explore" component={Explore} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here's the [code](https://github.com/theairbend3r/pokedex/tree/login-signup/frontend/src).

Comment: Can you show, how do you redirect after successful login?

Comment: The variable `authState` contains the `isUserLoggedIn` state. If `authState` is true, that means the user is logged in. If the login form on submit has the username and password as "test" and "test", I update the `authState` to true. By default `authstate` is false. So, when `authstate` become true, the page should redirect from `/` to `/home` which is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get back to the original component that you tried visiting is because even though you pass state as props.location, you are not using it to redirect back after login or signup

Grad the location state in Landing page and pass on to your ModalLogin and ModalSignup Component

```
const Landing = () => {
  const [loginModalBool, setLoginModalBool] = useState(false)
  const [signupModalBool, setSignupModalBool] = useState(false)
  const location = useLocation();
  const imageUrl =
    window.innerWidth >= 650 ? desktop_wallpaper : mobile_phone_wallpaper

  return (
    <div
      css={[
        tw`flex flex-1 flex-col items-center justify-around h-screen w-full`,
        css`
          background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
            url(${imageUrl});
          ${tw`bg-auto bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat`}
        `,
      ]}
    >
      <div>
        <h1 tw="text-white text-4xl md:text-4xl lg:text-6xl font-bold">
          Pokedex
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div tw="flex flex-col text-white">
        {signupModalBool === true ? (
          <ModalSignup
            fromState={location.state && location.state.from}
            signupModalBool={signupModalBool}
            setSignupModalBool={setSignupModalBool}
          />
        ) : loginModalBool === true ? (
          <ModalLogin 
            fromState={location.state && location.state.from}
            loginModalBool={loginModalBool}
            setLoginModalBool={setLoginModalBool}
          />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <ButtonBase onClick={() => setLoginModalBool(!loginModalBool)}>
              log in
            </ButtonBase>
            <ButtonBase onClick={() => setSignupModalBool(!signupModalBool)}>
              sign up
            </ButtonBase>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Landing
```

Post that you can use this value after dispatching login action

```
const ModalLogin = props => {
  const { loginModalBool, setLoginModalBool } = props
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const history = useHistory();
  const attemptLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(
      login({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
    )
    history.push(props.fromState || '/home');
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple. Check the code below.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = (props) => {
   const history = useHistory();
   
   useEffect(() => {
      // history.replace replaces current URL with new URL
      history.replace('/');   

      // history.push adds a new URL to the browser's history
      history.push('/');   
   },[])
}
```

you need to decide as per requirement which of the following to use.